# Looking for a jQuery scrollbar plugin that works with jQuery UI Sortable scroll:true

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scrollbar, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi does anyone know of a jQuery scrollbar plugin that styles scrollbars (divs) and works with jQuery UI's Sortable method with scroll: true?

I've tried these two:

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="purpose-scroll">
    <ul class="ui-sortable">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The scrollbar plugin is applied to the div and jQuery UI's sortable is applied to the UL tag inside id. When there are more items then fit on the screen a styled scrollbar appears. Trying to grab and item and drag it to the bottom to make the div scroll doesn't work. I'm looking for a solution that will style the scrollbar and have it scroll when I drag past the top/bottom edges.

I'm using the latest version of jQuery and jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

http://www.codexperience.co.za/post/creating-custom-scrollbars-in-minutes

Its not a plugin but will teach you how to create custom scrollbars in under 20 minutes. They work on every browser. Even IE8 (proven)

I'm hoping that once you roll out your own then you have to worry about them not working when you sort your list out